# firebase auth signInWithCustomToken on safari web extension not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, safari-web-extension

Firebase auth with signInWithCustomToken not working on Safari web extension.
also firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential) not working.
the code is executed from the content script.

```js
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).then((res)=> {

}, (err)=> {

})
// i am not getting any response. not even error.
```

on chrome extension everything works fine. any idea why its not working?

Comment: any idea why its not working?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm running into the same issue